# linq2sql to group results

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

My sql stored procedure returns following output.

```
type_id description
------- -----------

1        Name details
3       FirstName
3       SurName
1      Address details
3      firstLine
3      LastLine
1      Employment details
2      occupation
3      salary
```

type_id of 1 is parent and its children are displayed below.(until i read another parent)

i am using Linq2Sql and i like to convert this to Dictionary< string ,List < string > >

for example

```
Name details  
  firstName  
  SurName  
Address details   
  firstLine  
  LastLine  
Employment details  
   occupation  
   salary
```

Is it possible in linq ?

Comment: There's no way to address the "next few" records as children, no.  You'd have to roll through them building your `Dictionary` the old fashioned way.

Comment: And if there is a way to squeeze this into linq, the classical way is probably more lucid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to address the "next few" records as children, no.  You'd have to roll through them building your `Dictionary` the old fashioned way.